# Youtube api or other api for not allowed usage

Tags: android, api, youtube

I am making an app for android which allow user to play `youtube video` in background. I know youtube does not allow to do that but i want to have this app for personal use. Should i use the official youtube api or an external api (made by users). I want to use an api for searching on youtube and for `streaming` the audio.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use it youtube itself provide api for developers you can see this on https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/api-resources.html

to start working with youtube api with android visit this link for more detail :

[youtube with android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

Comment: In order to use the youtube api, you must "including your digitally signed .apk file's public certificate in the Google Developers Console". Won't they deny the acces to this app cause the app does not respect the terms of use ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: to register your app you can take help from this reference https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register